# Expression of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression cannot be used for parameter of type

Tags: c#, linq, expression, entity-framework-6

I created dynamic select for Type

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, TResult result)
{
    var resultType = typeof(TResult);
    var resultObj = Expression.New(resultType);
    var receiverProperties = resultType.GetProperties();
    var sourceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "item");
    var resultParameters = new List<MemberBinding>();

    foreach (var receiverProperty in receiverProperties)
    {
        var sourceProperty = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(receiverProperty.Name);

        if (sourceProperty != null)
        {
            var sourcePropertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(sourceParameter, sourceProperty);
            var memberInit = Expression.Bind(receiverProperty, sourcePropertyAccess);
            resultParameters.Add(memberInit);
        }
    }

    var selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MemberInit(resultObj, resultParameters), sourceParameter);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression.Call(
             null,
             ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult)),
             new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) }));
}
```

But this code return exception

> Expression of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Class1]]' cannot
>   be used for parameter of type 'Class2' of method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Class2]
>   Select[Class1,Class2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Class1], Class2)

Me need convertion? If yes - where?

**Update**

Error I get at

```
 return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression.Call(
             null,
             ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult)),
             new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) }));
```

Comment: Look at the two types in the error message.  One type is `Expression`, the other type is `IQueryable`.  The exception should be telling you what line of code is causing the error.  Which line of code is it?

Comment: What does this do, actually?  Have you seen PredicateBuilder?

Comment: PredicateBuilder didn't saw. But how I saw. They for logic operation. But about me I need create dynamic select.

Comment: What is a "dynamic select?"  Have you seen `System.Linq.Dynamic`?  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Not to make each time select(x=>new Class {Name = x.Name, ... })
but only
select(new Class)

Answer (score -1):

OK. I found answer at my question. It is problem with generation method witch we will call.

```
Expression.Call(
         null,
         ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult)),
         new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) })
```

For work, we need using

```
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable),
                    "Select",
                    new Type[] { source.ElementType, selector.Body.Type },
                    new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) });
```